# wrap code in notepad++

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I love notepad++ but I dislike when someone sends me an `.html` or `.xml` file and the entire code is on one line.  Is there a plugin or program that will take a one like code and indent it correctly on multiple lines?

Example:

```
<html><head><title></title></head><body><div></div></body><html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: That's... not word wrapping.

Comment: It's called Visual Studio.

Comment: I called it "word wrap" because I did not know what else to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [HTML tidy](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=HTML_Tidy) plugin available that correspond to your need. You can also install the TextFX plugin which adds a bunch of other enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin named XML tool which does the pretty print for you.
Use Plugin Manager (Menu Plugins->Plugin Manager) to install it.